# Background image not staying fixed in IE8 (anythingSlider)

Tags: css, background-position, anythingslider

Link referenced to in the text below: http://www.massgeneral.org/international/dev/full-screen.aspx

If you preview the CSS for the div with the class "anythingNavWindow", you can see a background image (sprite) that is being used to cast a shadow effect, giving the navigation window of the thumbnail slider the visual of the thumbnails being behind the triggers.

Well, unfortunately, when viewing in IE8, the shadow moves with the thumbnails when you transition using the sliders to view the additional thumbnails in the slider. Every other browser handles the background image properly, which is to have it be stationary and not move with the thumbnail slider.

The actual transition of the thumbnails is taking place on a parent container, not the parent container with the class "anythingNavWindow", so I'm not sure why this is occurring. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I don't believe this is an issue with the slider, but more of an issue with the CSS.

Here is a jsFiddle ready to be tampered with: http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/fKCFE/

```
div.anythingNavWindow {
    width: 616px !important; 
    background: url('http://www.massgeneral.org/assets/js-plugins/images/bg-slideshow-shadows.png') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Setting the position to "fixed", somehow ends up hiding the entire DIV container.
- Setting the background position using the "background-position-x" & "background-position-y" does nothing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY`

IE8 uses that, for some stupid reason.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of how to implement this or documentation on proper usage? Thanks!

Comment: I've really only seen it used with jQuery, but I'm sure it's the same if you go straight to css.

So it'd be like:

`div.anythingNavWindow {width:616px !important; backgroundPositionX: 0px; backgroundPositionY:0px }` or whatever

Comment: @JoeyO'Driscoll hmm. Maybe it's just a jQuery shortcut then. I can't think of a reason that it'd be doing what it's doing. Try validating your HTML just to make sure that IE isn't mixing up your elements. I've had that happen before with similar results. IE is notoriously bad at guessing what your DOM should look like.

Comment: I'm going to do additional tweaking to this, however, my initial attempt to use the backgroundPositionY/X attribute within jQuery didn't seem to work. I'll play with a jFiddle and see if I can fix it.